# codeigniter passing array from controller to view undefined index error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Passing the array to the view works fine after this line: `foreach($rb_data as $row){<table>}?>` but in my `<body>` above the table I am unable to use `<h1><?php echo $rb_data['brand'];?></h1>`
The error I receive is `Message: Undefined index: brand`. Ive tried initializing the array using `$data = array()` in the controller and this has not worked. Is there some other way to initialize the array so it can be used before the `foreach` statement? Thank you for taking a look.
Controller:

```
    public function community_single($rb){
        $data['rb_data'] =  $this->rootbeer_model->community_single($rb);
        $this->load->view('rb_community_single_view',$data);

    }
```

Model:

```
    public function community_single($rb){

        $this->rb_db->select('*');
        $this->rb_db->from('rb_selection');
        $this->rb_db->where('brand',$rb);
        $query = $this->rb_db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: Please post your actual controller code, and your output from `print_r($rb_data)` and clarify whether or not it is what you expect.

Comment: `print_r($rb_data);` returns `array()`. Not sure what to expect it to return. I am expecting `?php echo $rb_data['brand'];?>` to return bob at the top of my view the same way `?php echo $rb_data['brand'];?>` returns bob in my `foreach` loop and it is not.

Comment: Please post your controller code and any model code that is relevant. If `print_r($rb_data)` returns an empty array then I'm not sure why you would expect the key `brand` to be in it or why your foreach would print anything.

Comment: Do you expect multiple database results from `community_single()` or should there always be only one?

Comment: Well, doesn't that mean that `$rb_data` is array of arrays. If you had  at least one result you would access it by using `$rb_data[0]['brand']`

Comment: I still don't understand why the same statement in the `foreach` loop can return `$rb_data` values but the same echo will not return the data before this loop?

Comment: there can not be $rb_data['brand'];. result_array() returns array 0 => array('brand' => 'test', 'model' => 'test'), 1 => array('brand' => 'test2', 'model' => 'test2')

Comment: $rb_data[0]['brand'] will return brand name from 1st row, $rb_data[1]['brand'] will return brand name from second row and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `$this->rootbeer_model->community_single($rb);`
will return an array like this
ie, `rb_data=[[id=>1,value=>'a'],[id=>2,value=>'b'],[id=>3,value=>'c']]`

so first you need to fetch the row that you wand, using this functions,

```
1. foreach($rb_data as $row){<table>}?>

2. $row = $rb_data->first_row()
   $row = $rb_data->last_row()
   $row = $rb_data->next_row()
   $row = $rb_data->previous_row()

3.$row = $rb_data->row(5);
```

then you can access `$row['band']'

```
`$rb_data` doesn't contains an index like `band` . `$rb_data` contains only rows
```

Comment: Thanks Abin! `$rb_data[0]['brand'];` worked and this lead me there.

Answer (score 0):

I remember I was using `row_array()` for single calls. CodeIgniter has a good documentation even better than Windows. `result_array()` is used in loops if you pay attention.